# Java SimpleDateFormat Bug?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

Does anyone know why I get the output below?
I expected 2012-12 instead of 2013-12

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,12-1);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,30);
Date date=cal.getTime();
System.out.println(date);

String YYYY_MM=format.format(date);
System.out.println(YYYY_MM);
```

OUTPUT

```
Sun Dec 30 18:30:52 KST 2012
2013-12
```

EXPECTED

```
Sun Dec 30 18:30:52 KST 2012
2012-12
```

Comment: can you show the declaration of `format`? BTW, there will be no bug in `SimpleDateFormatter`, must be some misconfiguration

Comment: You have 2 `System.out.println` in your code. Can you post both results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using incorrect date formatter. You can try this way,

```
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,12-1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE,30);
    Date date=cal.getTime();
    System.out.println(date);
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM");
    // Java SimpleDateFormat use `yyyy` (lowercase) not `YYYY`(uppercase)
    String YYYY_MM=format.format(date);
    System.out.println(YYYY_MM); //out put 2012-12
```

Out put for me

```
Sun Dec 30 15:20:08 IST 2012
2012-12
```

Comment: should OP play spot the differences?